# How to clone a single specific file from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo with huge sources, but need to edit only one file.
Its taking more time and size to clone to local.
Can some one say the git command to clone a specific file from bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

Considering a BitBucket server now (since 2018) [has inline editing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-4-13-release-notes-867365635.html?), you could consider modifying that file directly through the browser.

That way, no clone is necessary.

Comment: And if you're using Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) there's been inline editing there for a lot longer.

Answer (score 1):

VonC's answer is great; I'd do that in most situations.

There are ways to get one file from Bitbucket:

```
$ curl --user <your_bitbucket_username> -O  https://bitbucket.org/<your_bitbucket_username>/<repo_name>/<filename>
```

You'll be able to edit the file, but it will be outside the context of `.git`, which doesn't seem to support your end goal of updating the repo.

Another option that still lets you clone the repo locally (for bigger edits, stuff you'd like to do with a text editor) is to clone it with less history:

```
$ git clone --depth=<a low number> <your_repo_url>
```

This can reduce the size of your total Git repo by a fraction of the total.

Checking `man git-clone` for more options, such as the `--shallow*` commands.